# Service bus relays and SignalR

Tags: azure, signalr

we are planning to use **SignalR** with **Windows Azure Service Bus** for a cloud application that requires live client updating (browsers). We might have about ***200*** clients connected to our solution. If we deploy our application over a 4 instances cloud service I know I should use the "*GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseWindowsAzureServiceBus(connectionString, 1);*" option to connect them through the service bus.

**My question is:** Will it use service bus relays? or topics? as many as hubs on each instance? one relay per client (200 clients) connected using SignalR? I just want to know how much they will [charge me](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=full) to know if it is worth it. In fact the most important thing to know here is if SignalR uses Topics/subscriptions or relays?

Thanks a lot for your help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SignalR Azure Service Bus scaleout provider will only use one subscription per role instance. If you have 4 cloud service instances, you will actually want:

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseWindowsAzureServiceBus(connectionString, 4);
```

The second parameter is your instance count.

This will put all of your SignalR messages on one topic. If you want to distribute you messages between more topics, you can specify a `topicCount` as the third parameter to `UseWindowsAzureServiceBus` like so:

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseWindowsAzureServiceBus(connectionString,
                                                        instanceCount: 4,
                                                        topicCount: 2);
```

NOTE: The parameters above are only named for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Halter73 but that brings me a new question, if we are using Azure and I can increase the amount of instances, can I change that value (instanceCount) dinamically so every instance can have all the hubs connected?

Comment: You can't change instanceCount dynamically, but SignalR 1.1 drops the need to specify an instanceCount.